# Color axis text to match grouping variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the `mpg` dataset to replicate the issue I am having. I would like the color of the categorical axis car `model` to match the grouping variable car `manufacturer`. Ideally, the figure would have all of the car models produced by a manufacturer grouped together with a unique text color for each manufacturer (e.g., audi a4 with audi a4 quattro, both text color "blue" and hyundai tiburon with hyundai sonata, both text color "pink", etc.).

Example data

```
dat <- mpg[mpg$cyl == 4,]
unique(dat$manufacturer)
cols <- c("audi" = "#a6cee3", "chevrolet" = "#1f78b4", "dodge" = "#b2df8a",
          "honda" = "#33a02c", "hyundai" = "#fb9a99","nissan" = "#e31a1c",
          "subaru" = "#fdbf6f","toyota" = "#ff7f00","volkswagen" = "#cab2d6")
```

I have tried making the car `model` text color match the `manufacturer` by `axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, color = cols[dat$manufacturer])` but this does not work properly (it only uses 4 colors and they do not match the manufacturer). It also does not group like manufacturers together which would be ideal.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = model, y = cty )) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2, fill = "white") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray85",linetype="longdash",size=0.1),
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, color = cols[dat$manufacturer]),
        legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: another close approximation come from the last figure [on this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpubr/readme/README.html) using ```ggpubr```. Still though, like manufacturers are not grouped together as would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be achieved via the `ggtext` package which via the theme element `element_markdown` allows text styling via HTML and CSS. To this end wrap the model name in a `span` tag to which you add your desired font color via the `style` attribute:

Note: Your color vector was missing a color for `subaru` for which I added `"purple"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

cols <- data.frame(manufacturer = names(cols), color = cols)
dat <- merge(dat, cols, by = "manufacturer", all.x = TRUE)

dat$model <- paste0("<span style=\"color: ", dat$color, "\">", dat$model, "</span>")

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = model, y = cty )) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2, fill = "white") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray85",linetype="longdash",size=0.1),
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 12),
        legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

**EDIT** To order by manufacturer you could first convert `manufacturer` to a `factor` with the levels set in your desired order. Afterwards order your `data` by `manufacturer` and convert the `model` column to a `factor` too which the order of the levels set according to the order in the re-arranged data. Last step could be achieved by using `unique()`:

```r
dat$manufacturer <- factor(dat$manufacturer, 
                           levels = c("toyota", "audi", "chevrolet", "dodge", "honda", 
                                      "hyundai", "nissan", "subaru", "volkswagen"))
dat <- dat[order(dat$manufacturer), ]
dat$model <- factor(dat$model, levels = unique(dat$model))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = model, y = cty )) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2, fill = "white") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray85",linetype="longdash",size=0.1),
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 12),
        legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! One last question, what if I wanted to change the order of the manufacturer groupings (e.g., Volkswagen at top and Toyota at the bottom)?

Comment: To order by manufacturer you have to convert to factors with the levels set in the desired order. Requires some fiddling but see my edit for an approach to achieve that.